# How to redirect to another website using a href in React

Tags: reactjs

in my application I need to redirect the user to a different website. I do not use a Router, but only a classic **a href** link.

If I add my props to the link. It doesn't redirect me to a new absolute address, but instead adds a relative address to my link.

`<a href={props.web}>{props.web}</a>`

When `props.web = stackoverflow.com`
so the resulting address looks like `https://myapp.com/stackoverflow.com`

Can you please help me add an absolute new redirect address without Router?

Thank you

Comment: try `https://stackoverflow.com` instead of `stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect to external website by giving full path including http:// or https://

```
props.web = https://stackoverflow.com
```